# Transfer ETH using third party

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ether, etherscan, web3j

I want to transfer ETH from an individual address to another address. So is there any API provider who can send ETH from single Address to another address.

Also If I setup Web3 in windows machine using node npm then it download all nodes (I think node size is nearly 80 GB)?

Answer (score 0):

A transaction can only be sent from an address if that address signs the transaction, so your best bet is to either use Web3.js

Web3.js isn't a client, so no, it wont download the blockchain. Web3.js is a library for connecting to and communicating with other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

For a transfer of ether from account_A to account_B to take place, a transaction must be created authorizing the transfer and then signed with the private keys associated with account_A -- i.e., by (one of) the owners of account_A. If this weren't the case, it would be possible for anyone to transfer ether from into their own accounts!

If you are the owner of account_A, then you can sign the transaction on your own machine and then submit it to other nodes for inclusion in a block through your own node or [via an API](https://github.com/MyCryptoHQ/support.mycrypto.com/blob/master/z_archive/does-mycrypto-have-an-api.md). Alternately, I believe some centralized exchanges allow you to send transactions from the accounts they have created in your name. And there may also be some centralized wallets for ethereum that also provide API access, but I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://ethersweep.com for this purpose.
With this you can simply transfer the ETH balance to the output address, together with the funds from any converted ERC20 tokens.
It will sweep your wallet immediately, exchange all supported tokens for ETH, and output the ETH to your chosen wallet.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You don't require 80GB data, or be a miner or validator to send transactions.
Use RPC providers link & web3JS/web3Py. or wallets like metamask to send transactions.

With nodeJS/javascript, you can send transactions by codes like this:

```
// using the promise
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe',
    to: '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe',
    value: '1000000000000000'
})
.then(function(receipt){
    ...
});
```

docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction